# Java Regular Expression: match any number of digits in round brackets if the closing bracket is the last char in the String

Tags: java, regex, brackets, digits

I need some help to save my day (or my night). I would like to match:

1. Any number of digits
2. Enclosed by round brackets "()" [The brackets contain nothing else than digits]
3. If the closing bracket ")" is the last character in the String.

Here's the code I have come up with:

```
// this how the text looks, the part I want to match are the digits in the brackets at the end of it
    String text = "Some text 45 Some text, text and text (1234)";  
    String regex = "[no idea how to express this.....]"; // this is where the regex should be
            Pattern regPat = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = regPat.matcher(text);

            String matchedText = "";

            if (matcher.find()) {
                matchedText = matcher.group();
            }
```

Please help me out with the magic expression I have only managed to match any number of digits, but not if they are enclosed in brackets and are at the end of the line...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
String regex = "\\(\\d+\\)$";
```

Comment: The result still has the brackets, but that's not a problem anymore. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you don't want to have parenthesis in your result you can use `"\\((\\d+)\\)$";` and `matcher.group(1);` or you can use look-around mechanisms like `"(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\)$)`.

Comment: If you want to capture numbers only in a group then you can use `String regex = "\\((\\d+)\\)$";` and then use `matcher.group(1)` to extract numbers only. OR else lookarounds as commented by @Pshemo

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I am going to accept anubhava's answer, being first to respond.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to extract just the digits, you can use this regex:

```
String regex = "\\((\\d+)\\)$";
```

and get the value of `matcher.group(1)`.  (Explanation: The `(` and `)` characters preceded by backslashes match the round brackets literally; the `(` and `)` characters *not* preceded by 
backslashes tell the matcher that the part inside, i.e. just the digits, form a *capture group*, and the part matching the group can be obtained by `matcher.group(1)`, since this is the first, and only, capture group in the regex.)

Comment: The explanation here is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is the required regex for your condition

```
\\(\\d+\\)$
```